# Flattening a Map<Integer, Map<String, Boolean>> to a List<Boolean>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using java 8 streams, how do I flatten a `Map<Integer, Map<String, Boolean>>` to just a `List<Boolean>` so that the final list will contain all the booleans across all values?

Here is an example of the data:

```
1 -> [{"ABC" -> true}, {"DEF" -> true}]
2 -> [{"DEF" -> false}, {"EFG" -> true}]
3 -> [{"ABC" -> true}, {"DEF" -> false}]
```

I want to flatten this to a `List<Boolean>` so that my list will contain:

```
{true, true, false, true, true, false}
```

Order is not important. Content is important.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried? so we can see if we can help?

Comment: Try out flatmap ... and maybe you want to present the problem you want to solve with it. I suspect that you won't need flattening a map, but grouping or reducing.

Comment: This is a strange requirement, what can you do with such a list? The only useful information will be the number of true/false. Or maybe you should read [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Boolean>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Boolean>>();
        final List<Boolean> collect = map
            .values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(it -> it.values().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
  final Map<Integer, List<Entry>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(1, Arrays.asList(new Entry("ABC", true), new Entry("DEF", true)));
  map.put(2, Arrays.asList(new Entry("DEF", false), new Entry("EFG", true)));
  map.put(3, Arrays.asList(new Entry("ABC", true), new Entry("DEF", false)));

  final List<Boolean> booleans = map.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
      .map(entry -> entry.value)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

  System.out.println(booleans);
```

But be aware that the order will not be saved here as this is a `HashMap`.

Comment: Why starting with an `.entrySet()` just to call `entry.getValue()` on each? You can start with `map.values()` in the first place, `map.values() .stream() .flatMap(list -> list.stream())`…

Comment: @Holger Can be replaced with `values()` however it doesn't change the complexity as you'd need `flatMap` + `map` anyway.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn’t change the complexity. Neither does appending `+ 0` to every numerical expression…

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the following:

```
final List<Boolean> collect = map.values().stream() // Stream<Map<String,Boolean>>
    .map(Map::values)                               // Stream<Collection<Boolean>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)                    // Stream<Boolean>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The difference from this and the other answers provided is, that every line only contains **one** operation (which I *personally* prefer, its more readable).

Comment: The difference is that you added comments which help understanding what happens. Especially helpful for beginners, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> I want to flatten this to a List so that my list will contain: {true, true, false, true, true, false}

the solution could be like this

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Boolean>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, new HashMap<String, Boolean>(){{put("ABC", true);put("DEF", true);}});
    map.put(2, new HashMap<String, Boolean>(){{put("DEF", false);put("EFG", true);}});
    map.put(3, new HashMap<String, Boolean>(){{put("ABC", true);put("DEF", false);}});

    System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream().flatMap( t -> t.getValue().values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: seems like the same exact answer as here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47733489/1059372